# Will I have any issues if I upgrade from .NET 4.0 to 4.5 for 2016

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, upgrade

This old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545438/will-i-have-any-issues-if-i-upgrade-from-net-4-0-to-4-5) is related but is dated. Issues that were brought up are apparently resolved. So I'd like to ask the same question again but for 2016.

1. Are there any breaking changes in 4.5 that are likely to throw my
   4.0 app offline

Comment: Well, what changed in 2016? .Net 4.5.2 and 4.6 are released. But if you are installing .Net 4.5.2, then the question will be the same as that one

Comment: The situation is that Microsoft no longer supports .NET 4.0 and you must be using .NET 4.5.2 and above.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very well documented by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657133(v=vs.110).aspx), but some key aspects can be mentioned on this site, as the documentation is pretty long:

1) **Application Compatibility** - this is covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx) exactly for your desired transition (4.0 -> 4.5). It includes some changes regarding multi-threading (Tasks and co.), `System.Uri`, `System.Data.SqlClient`, Entity Framework's `ObjectContext`, `XmlSerializer` and many other features. Depending on project type and features used, you should take a look for that particular section

**2) Obsolete/deprecated features** - covered in detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502(v=vs.110).aspx) (and provided links there), will be shown after compiling upgraded projects. Here, the easiest approach is to just tackle obsolete warnings one by one.

3) **What's new** - after performing the upgrade, you should definitely consider the goodies the come with the new framework. For 4.5 they are covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#core) and include very large arrays (>2G), major improvements for [parallelism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/17/10212961.aspx), ASP.NET improvements and many others

**4) NuGet packages** - If you have used NuGet, some packages will require upgrade. One way to ensure that the packages folder does not contain unused packages is to remove all content and allow Visual Studio to restore the actual used packages (does this by default on build).

Overall, the upgrade should run without any major problems and I recommend you to perform it.